# Modify checkbox behavior in vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have this checkbox

```html
<div class="form-check form-check-inline col-lg-2">
  <input v-model="propertyData.fitness_centre" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="dc_li_u" />
  <label class="form-check-label" for="dc_li_u">Fitness Centre</label>
</div>
```

and i am saving the state in a  database so when editing the state is restored and displays whether the checkbox was checked or not.

However, i need the checkbox to have a string value that is saved to the database when the checkbox is clicked such that when a checkbox has a string value, its checked and when the string value is empty the checkbox is not checked.

I have many checkboxes and so, i wanted the entire logic to be contained inside the checkbox. How can i modify the checkbox to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `true-value` and `false-value` attributes, to assign specific values when checking/unchecking.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
      fitness_centre: "true value"
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline col-lg-2">
    <input v-model="fitness_centre" true-value="true value" false-value="" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="dc_li_u" />
    <label class="form-check-label" for="dc_li_u">Fitness Centre</label>
    <div>Value: {{ fitness_centre }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice, much simpler than mine

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `change`-event handler to set `propertyData.fitness_centre` to the desired value based on the checked state. Also bind `<input>.checked` to `propertyData.fitness_centre` so that the checked state is bound to the model's truthiness (empty string is `false`, otherwise `true`).

```html
<template>
  <input type="checkbox"
         @change="onChange"
         :checked="propertyData.fitness_centre"
         value="fitness_centre">
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      propertyData: { fitness_centre: '' }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onChange(e) {
      this.propertyData.fitness_centre = e.target.checked ? e.target.value : ''
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/checkbox-radio-value-2bc0y?file=/src/App.vue)